# Unable to getImage from request.getInputStream()

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee

I am trying to get a image bytes from the request attribute which is coming from a mobile applciation.

The format of the  image that is sent upstream is BitMap.
Encoded in Base64 Format.

How to get the  bytes in the web application ?
I am using the below code snippet in my web application which i am using to get the data from the mobile applicaition request.
I am got struck with the code. I am not sure whether I am right or wrong.

```
byte[] line             = null;

    int noOfBytesRead;
    StringBuffer content    = new StringBuffer();

    HashMap<String, Object> lResultMap  =   null ;

    try 
    {
        log.info("request getInputStream: " + request.getInputStream());
        ServletInputStream sis  = request.getInputStream();

        line                    = new byte[128];
        noOfBytesRead           = sis.readLine(line, 0, 128);
        log.info("noOfBytesRead :1 " + noOfBytesRead);

        if (noOfBytesRead < 3)
            return null;

        noOfBytesRead           = sis.readLine(line, 0, 128); // Reads the content disposition and form name and filename

        log.info("line :"+line+" adn the noOfBytesRead : 2 : "  +   noOfBytesRead);

        int numBytesToRead      = noOfBytesRead;
        int availableBytesToRead;

        while ((availableBytesToRead = sis.available()) > 0) 
        {
            byte[] bufferBytesRead;
            bufferBytesRead     = availableBytesToRead >= numBytesToRead ? new byte[numBytesToRead] : new byte[availableBytesToRead];
            sis.read(bufferBytesRead);
            content.append(new String(bufferBytesRead, Charset.forName("iso-8859-1")));
        }
        sis.close();
        log.info("The bytes is  : " +content.toString());
        byte[] image        =   null;
        image   =   content.toString().getBytes(Charset.forName("iso-8859-1")) ;
        log.info("image : "  +image);


        Base64Decoder decoder = new Base64Decoder();  
        byte[] imgBytes = decoder.decode(content.toString());
        log.info("imgBytes : decoded byted" + imgBytes);        
        lResultMap          =   new HashMap<String, Object>();

        lResultMap.put("content"    , imgBytes );
        log.info("content string buffer :  " +content);
        log.info("lResultMap : "  +lResultMap);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

its hard to make sense from your code as its not formatted but here is my simple solution

```
URL url = new URL(contentUrl);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        InputStream inStr = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream buffInStr = new BufferedInputStream(inStr);
        // Need to check the size of Byte Array Buffer.
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(500);
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = buffInStr.read()) != -1) {
            baf.append((byte) current);
        }
        byte[] array = baf.toByteArray();
```

On google app engine

The Image service API accepts data in any of the supported image file formats. According to [this page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/overview), these formats include "JPEG, PNG, WEBP, GIF (including animated GIF), BMP, TIFF and ICO". The Image service does not provide a way to create new image data from scratch. But you can use a graphics library to produce the image in one of the accepted data formats, then use the service to convert it to another format, or transform it. Of course, depending on the graphics library, you may be able to get the final image directly from the library, and not use the service.

To serve an image, just set the appropriate Content-Type header for the data format you're using, then write the bytes of the image data to the response's output stream:

```
// byte[] pngData = ...
resp.addHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");
resp.getOutputStream().write(pngData);
```

If you want to try generating the image data without a library, the BMP format might be easiest. You can use the Images service to convert this to PNG.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Sorry for the bad formatting.I am new to use these kind of codes can u pls tell what the contenturl means ?

Comment: Contenturl is a string url from where you need to download image if this solve your problem can you accept my answer

Comment: Iam getting image as bytes from mobile application I should get the bytes from the request and it is an appengine project.
How to get the Image as bytes from the request ?

Comment: i didnt get what u want to say

Comment: Sorry, I uploading image from mobile and calling a webservice which receives the bytes and create back the image. There i am getting problem

Comment: decoding byte array to bitmap using bitmap factory will solve thi s

Comment: Ill try and let you know soon.